Data-transformation with R and dplyr
I have data in the following format:



Location
Species
Date
Count




Location1
Species1
01-01-2024
2


Location1
Species1
01-02-2024
4


Location1
Species1
01-03-2024
3


Location1
Species2
01-01-2024
6


Location1
Species2
01-03-2024
3



And I want to transform it with r and dplyr into something like this:



Location
Species
First Date
Last Date
Date with Max Count
Max Count




Location1
Species1
01-01-2024
01-03-2024
01-02-2024
4


Location1
Species2
01-01-2024
01-03-2024
01-01-2024
6



I have some complicated ideas, but maybe there is a very easy solution to do this?

df |> summarize(First_Date = min(Date), Last_Date = max(Date), Date_max = Date[Count == max(Count)], Max_Count = max(Count), .by = c(Location, Species))? What do you want to happen if two dates have the same max count?

The following should achieve your desired result and makes use of the the dplyr package:
  # Data
mydata <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          Location = c("Location1","Location1",
                       "Location1","Location1","Location1"),
           Species = c("Species1","Species1",
                       "Species1","Species2","Species2"),
              Date = c("01-01-2024","01-02-2024",
                       "01-03-2024","01-01-2024","01-03-2024"),
             Count = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L)
)
  # Code 
library(dplyr)

result <- mydata %>%
      group_by(Location, Species) %>%
      summarise(
        First_Date = min(Date),
        Last_Date = max(Date),
        Date_with_Max_Count = max(Date[which.max(Count)]),
        Max_Count = max(Count),
        .groups = 'drop'
      )

If two dates have the same max count, I'm returning the most recent date in this code.  If you want the first date, you'd replace max(Date[which.max(Count)]) with min(Date[which.max(Count)]).  If you wanted something more complicated, you could simply write a function for that and replace the min/max functions with your custom function.
